# Dragging functionality not working on Android Studio 2.3?

Tags: android-studio

This is the **Component tree** of my application.

[image]

I wanted to move the `textView` to the center. However, we can do that manually setting the properties of that element in the `Text` tab. But I suppose setting the properties manually doesn't align the elements properly on the UI.

[image]

There should be some way to drag the elements on the `Design` page. But then, I'm not able to drag the `textView` to which ever position I want.

> Can anyone tell me how do I drag the '`textView`' to the **center** ?

Answer (score 0):

Even I'm facing the same problem. But, aligning an element to the `center` can be done using this property `android:layout_gravity="center"`
You can choose which ever position you like.

Comment: This answer somehow helped me to get through one problem. But I wanted to make use of Drag feature on the `Design` tab